# Graph predicate in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph

I need to determine if the list is a directed graph

I wrote such code:

```
type Graph = [[Int]]

isGraph :: Graph -> Bool
isGraph :: Graph -> Bool
isGraph graph =isGraphFor graph 1 where
    isGraphFor gr cur 
        |cur > length gr = True
        |otherwise = (foldl (&&) True (map (isInList) (getAccessibleEdges gr cur))) && (isGraphFor gr (cur+1)) where
            isInList edge = cur `elem` (getAccessibleEdges gr edge)

getAccessibleEdges :: Graph -> Int -> [Int]
getAccessibleEdges gr edge = dfsEdges gr [] (gr!!(edge-1))

dfs :: Graph -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
dfs gr st cur = cur: (dfsEdges gr (cur:st) (gr !! (cur-1)))

dfsEdges :: Graph -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
dfsEdges _ _ [] = []
dfsEdges gr st (x:xs) = 
    if not (x `elem` st) then 
       let new = dfs gr st x
       in  new ++ (dfsEdges gr (new++st) xs) 
    else 
       dfsEdges gr st xs
```

But when I give such input [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]] the answer is false.
Please, help me to solve my problem

Comment: The code is not very readable at the moment. Maybe if you pull the functions you use as arguments to the folds out and annotate, we might be able to help.

Comment: I edit my code by another way, but it didn`t work properly(

Comment: If the intent is to represent a graph as a list of edges between nodes represented by integers, then `[(Int, Int)]` would be a much better type.

Comment: The task is to use adjancy matrix